# How to match Tree map value which starts with or equals search string

Tags: java, regex, treemap

I have a tree map

```
    TreeMap<String,HashSet<String>> kewordVideo = new TreeMap<String,HashSet<String>>();
```

and

```
 String searchString;
```

I want to print all the values of Tree map which Starts with or equals searchString

For example Tree map has following key value pair

```
v1 abc
v2 abd
v3 bcd
v4 bad
```

and searchString is a

So output should be

```
v1 v2
```

as both of them start with a v4 should not be part of output as it does not starts with a or equals to a
Here is complete code . No output is coming after i enter search key

```
 package cultureMachine;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.util.HashSet;
 import java.util.Map;
 import java.util.Map.Entry;
 import java.util.Set;
 import java.util.TreeMap;

 public class CultureMachineAssignment {

 TreeMap<String,HashSet<String>> kewordVideo = new      TreeMap<String,HashSet<String>>();
TreeMap<String,HashSet<String>> videoKeyword =  new TreeMap<String,HashSet<String>>();
TreeMap<String,Integer> keywordLength = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

     CultureMachineAssignment obj1 = new CultureMachineAssignment();


     Integer previousVal=0;
     InputStreamReader ip = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ip);

     for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        System.out.println("Enter Video name");
        String video =br.readLine();


        if(!obj1.videoKeyword.containsKey(video)){
            obj1.videoKeyword.put(video,new HashSet<String>());
        }

        System.out.println("Enter keywords for video");
        String keyword =br.readLine();

        if(!obj1.keywordLength.containsKey(video))
            obj1.keywordLength.put(video, 0);

        if((obj1.keywordLength.get(video)+keyword.length())<5){
            obj1.videoKeyword.get(video).add(keyword);
            previousVal=obj1.keywordLength.get(video);
            obj1.keywordLength.put(video, previousVal+keyword.length());
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Maximum length exceeded for video "+ video);
            break;
        }
        if(!obj1.kewordVideo.containsKey(keyword)){
            obj1.kewordVideo.put(keyword,new HashSet<String>());
        }
        obj1.kewordVideo.get(keyword).add(video);


    }
    for(Map.Entry m:obj1.videoKeyword.entrySet()){  
        System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue());  
    }
    System.out.println("Enter keyword to search video");
    String searchKey = br.readLine();
    for(Entry<String,HashSet<String>> entry : obj1.kewordVideo.entrySet()){    
                  if(entry.getValue().contains(searchKey))
                     System.out.println(entry.getKey());

                }
        }   
 }
```

Comment: You forgot to explain problem which is stopping you from writing your own solution. What is the problem you are facing? Do you know how to iterate over map key-value pairs?

Comment: Yes I know I want to do it using regular expression `if(obj1.kewordVideo.containsKey(searchKey))` this is giving me if search string fully matches how to do for starts with

Comment: Can you add to your question code you are using? Also can you explain why you think you need regex (have you seen `startsWith` method from String)?

Comment: Anyway your question "*I want to print all the values of Tree map which Starts with or equals searchString*" is a little confusing since values of your TreeMap are HashSets of strings, not single string objects. So how do you decide which HashSet is correct for your `searchString`?

Comment: its hashset not hashmap

Comment: Thanks, edited my comment. But question stays, how do you want to decide which `HashSet` should be valid for your `searchString`? Remember that HashSets do not have guaranteed order.

Comment: What is not clear for me is that we don't know what `v1 abc` represents. Is it something like `vi -> [abc]` where value `abc` represents single element in your `HashSet` or maybe you wanted it to represent `v1 -> [a, b, c]` where `a` `b` `c` are separate elements in your set? Both cases requires different approaches. Also if `abc` represents `[a, b, c]` set then you need to know that elements of HashSet have no guaranteed order so if you want to check if first element is `a` (or starts with `a`) then results will depend on order which was currently used by HashSet (it depends on its size).

Comment: Here v1 abc means v1->[abc]

Comment: So can we assume that your set will always contain only one element? If not and lets say it contains `v5 -> [bca, abc]` and you are looking for `a`, should we print `v5` here?

Comment: yes as v5 contact abc but not for bca

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
TreeMap<String,HashSet<String>> videoKeyword = new TreeMap<String,HashSet<String>>();
videoKeyword.put("v1", new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("abc")));
videoKeyword.put("v2", new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("abd")));
videoKeyword.put("v3", new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("bcd")));
videoKeyword.put("v4", new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("bad")));

String searchString = "a";

for (Entry<String, HashSet<String>> entry : videoKeyword.entrySet()) {
    for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
        if (s.startsWith(searchString)) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
v1
v2
```

Comment: for `for(String s: entry){` I am getting following error `Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable`. Also can we use HashSet as I am using TreeMap

Comment: I fixed that in an edit. The `HashSet` is in fact `entry.getValue()`.

Comment: Is it necessary to iterate over the entire set of strings for each hashset?

Comment: @adam5990, yes it is necessary because the requirement is that the string **start with** the search word. If it were that the string be equal, `HashSet.contains()` would have worked directly, instead of the inner for-loop.

Comment: Ah, yes you are right, I should have read the question more carefully. In that case however, could you not get a small performance boost by testing using contains first before iterating over the strings within the string set, since no point in iterating if none of the values even contain the string at all?

Comment: @adam5990, Well `contains` will *only* tell you if the map contains the *exact* search word, which I guess is more of an exceptional case. But `contains` will not tell you if one of the `String`s inside the map contains the search word.

Comment: @EricLeibenguth, Thanks, that is good to know, I'm used to the behavior of contains in the context of individual Strings and the Java docs didn't seem to explicitly outline this but it does make sense logically.

Comment: I've  addec complete code . its not giving output after adding your suggestion can you help me please

Comment: The code in your post is not the one I posted. Please note that `entry.getValue().contains(searchKey)` returns false if entry = v1->[abc] and searchKey = "a". It returns true only if searchKey = "abc". This is why you need the double for-loop.

Comment: @EricLeibenguth You should probably break your inner loop when one of sets elements will start with searched string. Otherwise you will print key for each element in set which will match our criteria (like `v5 abc acb` would print v5 two times, unless that is what OP wants, but it would be strange to print key without each unique value which it was able to match).

Comment: @Pshemo, true! I fix it.

Comment: @ Eric I tried with your code too same no output After debugg  I found out this condition is not passed`  if (s.startsWith(searchKey)) {`

Comment: I just ran your code, replacing your last for-loop with mine. It works but **be carefull**: You need to loop through the `videoKeyword` map. It won't work with `kewordVideo`!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by iterating over your entry set in the tree map and testing for your search string using the contains method of hash set to identify which keys have values containing your search word.

```
for(Entry<String,HashSet<String>> entry : kewordVideo.entrySet()){     
  if(entry.getValue.contains(searchString){
    //Do something with entry.getKey(), ie add to a list or output to console
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not displaying output i tried debugging its not getting debugg too